# Autolayout rendering issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, interface-builder, autolayout

I am creating a custom UIView from a NIB file (my view has the Size set to iPhone - 4.7-inch). I want to add my custom view to the view controller in the `viewDidLoad` method.

Everything works as expected in the simulator when running on iPhone 6. However, if I change the device to a smaller screen (iPhone 5S or iPhone 4), I can see a animation as the view gets rendered on the screen (from the size it has in the NIB file to the new screen constraints). How can I add the view without that animation?

**EDIT:** Here the code from the view controller that instantiates and adds the custom view:

```
- (void)createLaunchScreen {
    LaunchScreen *launchScreen = [[LaunchScreen alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:launchScreen];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self createLaunchScreen];
    ...
}
```

The code from my custom view:

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        UIView *view = nil;
        NSArray *objects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LaunchScreen"
                                                         owner:self options:nil];
        for (id object in objects) {
            if ([object isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
                view = object;
                break;
            }
        }

        [self addSubview:view];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {
        view.frame = self.bounds;
    }
}
```

And here is an image with how my NIB file looks like
[image]

Comment: is that animation an issue caused due to change the of screen? or is it created somewhere in the code?

Comment: Please show us the code.

Answer (score 0):

Is it because you are showing it twice? That it is automatically loading up "LaunchScreen.xib" automatically displaying that and then loading up your custom view code which then resizes?

I would comment out your custom view code and see if the image doesn't display at all (or is there and not resized). If it still display (without the animation) then that's the problem.

Try changing your "Launch screen File" target setting from "LaunchScreen" to "Main.Storyboard"